# Ember route has action

Tags: ember.js

I am building a mixin for different routes to handle a save action. Sometimes after saving I want to do extra things, so I want to send a saveCallback action back to the route.

Is it possible to ask to a route if a action is defined? Or else: can I retrieve all functions of a route, so I could check myself if a route is defined?

**Code mixin**:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    actions: {
        save: {
            var self = this;

            this.get('model').save()
            .then(function(result) {
                //do stuff

                //Something like if(self.hasDefined('saveCallBack')) {
                    self.send('saveCallback')
                }
            }, function(errorReason) {
                //error handling
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I can't just fire the send action, as a `Nothing handled the action 'saveCallback'` error is thrown if the action is not defined.

Comment: Why not put 'saveCallback' in the application route. If your routes dont handle the action, the application route should just swallow it.

Comment: That does work indeed, but I would not call it very clean though. Just putting a function anywhere to prevent errors is not my cup of tea. Still, thx for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the issue now, but I read an issue on Github at some point about adding a `canSendAction` (or something similar) function for this reason. For now, just define the same action on your mixin, and have it bubble.

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    actions: {
        save: function() {
            var self = this;

            this.get('model').save().then(function() {
                self.send('saveCallback');
            });
        },

        saveCallback: function() {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: I'm being dumb. Just return `true` and the action should bubble up the hierarchy and will be caught by another action if it exists.

Comment: Seems to work exactly as I want it to be! Just a litte question: it seems that if you got a mixin with a saveCallBack-function and a Route (that extends with the mixin) with a saveCallBack-function, only the funcation of the Route's does fire. If only my mixin got that saveCallBack function, it does fire there. Is this intentional behaviour?

Comment: In that scenario, you kind of have two `saveCallback` actions defined on a single object. To call them both, you probably want to call `this._super()` at the start of each one. That will make sure that both are fired, no matter what order they're declared in. It's a bit weird, but bubbling an action and calling the super action are different.